# UML symbol for request with multiple responses

Tags: flowcharts, diagram

In our cloud infrastructure we receive customer requests and depending on the request and internal state, we return one of several possible kinds of responses.  Sometimes the set of possible kinds of responses is 2, sometimes it's 5 or 10.  The customers need to handle them all and the handling depends on the the response we provide.  I'm developing flow diagrams and I'm trying to find a symbol that would represent one incoming request and multiple possible responses.  Is there such a thing?

Perhaps there's a better way to look at the problem?

Comment: Hi Rom, welcome to SE UX site, you're probably not on ideal SE site. UX deals with http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but you may get a pointer.

Comment: Are you looking for a *sequence diagram*?  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html)

Comment: @Jørn: no, I'm looking for a symbol for a flowchart (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) that would represent 1-in N-out process.  Both answers so far are correctly identifying the process, but I'm hoping there is be a single symbol for it.

Comment: OK. FWIW: there's nothing called "Flowchart" in the [UML universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language). They have various "Behavior diagrams", and both ["sequence diagrams"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) and ["activity diagrams"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) might be what you're looking for...  Is the "UML"-part of your question less important?  Are you just working with a generic flow chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is a [decision node with multiple guards as per this example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#decision-node)

*There is NO single symbol*. Multiple possible conditions are handled by the normal decision nodes (flow control, or "IF" block) is used, but one has different guards (or criteria) for each route.

*Why no single symbol?*  It is a common misconception that UML is about "diagrams". UML is about a model of software, one (almost) strict enough to generate running system.. The UML model is carefully crafted to (a) have same syntax and semantics across the model and thus attached diagrams, and (b) a minimal language that is composed to cover broad range of semantics.

Comment: This answer is the best approach to the symbol I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: Nice resource! +1

Answer (score 2):

I believe that an [*activity diagram*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) is the [ULM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)-diagram you're looking for...

In the activity diagram, you use a black bar to indicate the start or end of concurrent activities:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the idea!  Unfortunately the meaning of this symbol is not what I'm looking for.  This symbol means that it will start ALL child processes once the incoming criteria is met.  I'm looking for a symbol that means that only one process will be started, depending on the result of the operation.  Essentially, I'm looking for the decision diamond, but without predefined number of outputs.

Answer (score 0):

In UML or database diagrams there are a few ways to denote a "[one to many](https://www.google.com/search?q=uml%20one%20to%20many%20symbol)" relationship.

The typical option is to use an asterisk `*` on the side w/multiple outputs.
See "[Association Qualifier](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html#qualifier)" here for examples.

A "1" on both sides of an arrow connecting 2 entities/processes indicates a "one-to-one" relationship, whereas `1..*` on a side indicates at least one match up to some arbitrary number. You could also use zero in a range like `0..*` to indicate you might not have any matches at all. Whatever fits your needs.

A graphical alternative is an [arrow with multiple 'forks'](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc02/pap0437/p04371.gif) on the side with multiple outputs.

Comment: So in flowchart after a decision (diamond) each transition can be configured with a different guard statement.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a placeholder to jump to a separate page which breaks down the decisions which go into the response.  Not sure how close this is to gospel UML, but hopefully it conveys what I am talking about.

[image: Multi-Branch UML]

Finally, you might add a comment to the primary document, telling the reader where to find the secondary document (page#, bottom of this page, etc.)